# How can I make this menu's "clear:both" work in Google Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've built a simple site with a nav menu that has the clear:both CSS style applied. On this site, there is a basic logo and a set of icons. The logo is floated left, while the icons are floated right. The site looks like this in Firefox and Chrome...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPYuL.jpg

The difference is that Chrome isn't accepting the clear:both (applied to the menu's div) within the CSS file. How can I get it to work?

Here's the HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>

<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />



<script type="text/javascript">

function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}

function MM_swapImgRestore() { //v3.0
  var i,x,a=document.MM_sr; for(i=0;a&&i<a.length&&(x=a[i])&&x.oSrc;i++) x.src=x.oSrc;
}

function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p,i,x;  if(!d) d=document; if((p=n.indexOf("?"))>0&&parent.frames.length) {
    d=parent.frames[n.substring(p+1)].document; n=n.substring(0,p);}
  if(!(x=d[n])&&d.all) x=d.all[n]; for (i=0;!x&&i<d.forms.length;i++) x=d.forms[i][n];
  for(i=0;!x&&d.layers&&i<d.layers.length;i++) x=MM_findObj(n,d.layers[i].document);
  if(!x && d.getElementById) x=d.getElementById(n); return x;
}

function MM_swapImage() { //v3.0
  var i,j=0,x,a=MM_swapImage.arguments; document.MM_sr=new Array; for(i=0;i<(a.length-2);i+=3)
   if ((x=MM_findObj(a[i]))!=null){document.MM_sr[j++]=x; if(!x.oSrc) x.oSrc=x.src; x.src=a[i+2];}
}
  </script>


    <title>Matiny's Sample Site 1</title>
</head>


<body onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/thumbs/A%20Thumbnail%202.jpg','images/thumbs/B%20Thumbnail%202.jpg','images/thumbs/S%20Thumbnail%202.jpg','images/thumbs/J%20Thumbnail%202.jpg','images/thumbs/T%20Thumbnail%202.jpg','images/thumbs/P%20Thumbnail%202.jpg','images/thumbs/A Thumbnail 2.jpg','images/thumbs/B Thumbnail 2.jpg','images/thumbs/S Thumbnail 2.jpg','images/thumbs/J Thumbnail 2.jpg','images/thumbs/T Thumbnail 2.jpg','images/thumbs/P Thumbnail 2.jpg')">


<div id="main">

    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/Icons/Logo.png"/>
    </div>

    <div id="sm-icons">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="images/Icons/facebook_64.png" id="Image7" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image7','','images/Icons/facebook_64 2.png',0)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"/></a>
          <li><a href="https://www.rss.com/"><img src="images/Icons/rss_64.png" id="Image8" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image8','','images/Icons/rss_64 2.png',0)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"/></a>
          <li><a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="images/Icons/twitter_64.png" id="Image9" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image9','','images/Icons/twitter_64 2.png',0)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"/></a>
          <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="images/Icons/youtube_64.png" id="Image10" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image10','','images/Icons/youtube_64 2.png',0)" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()"/></a>
      </ul>
    </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">WELCOME</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="">The Man</a></li>
                <li><a href="">The Myth</a></li>
                <li><a href="">The Legend</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="games.html">GAMES</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="galleries/Ezio.html">Assasin's Creed 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="galleries/Bruce.html">Batman Arkham City</a></li>
                <li><a href="galleries/Rico.html">Just Cause 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="galleries/Prince.html">Prince of Persia</a></li>
                <li><a href="galleries/Boss.html">Saints Row 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="galleries/TDU2.html">Test Drive Unlimited 2</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>

 </div>
```

And here's the CSS...

```
/* CSS Document */

/* Reset */

html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;  background: #000; font-size:16px; }


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, li, blockquote, td, th, a, caption, em, strong, strike { 
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 100%; 
    text-indent: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    }

/* Divisions */



#main { width:900px; margin:0 auto; background-color:#FFF; padding: 30px 100px;}

#logo { margin:30px; float:left}

#sm-icons { float:right; }
#sm-icons ul li  {display:inline}
#sm-icons ul {margin-top: 30px}

#menu {clear:both;
    width: 800px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    z-index: 6;
    position: relative;
} 
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#menu ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#menu ul li a {
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #CCC;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 50px;

    transition: background .5s, font-size .2s;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    font-size: 120%;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #CCC;
}
#menu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
#menu ul li ul li a {
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    opacity:.5;

    transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
#menu ul li:hover ul li a {
    height: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
    transition: all .3s ease-out;

}


#banner-pictures {margin-bottom: 50px}

#central-content    { width: 800px; text-align:center; margin:25px auto;}

#central-max width  { width: 100%; }

#footer {clear:both; border-top: 1px #666 solid}


/* Text Elements */

p               { color:#000; font-size:14px; line-height:120%;
                    margin:15px 0; margin-bottom: 30px  }
p .left         { margin: 1.5em 1.5em 1.5em 0; padding: 0; }
p .right        { margin: 1.5em 0 1.5em 1.5em; padding: 0; }



blockquote      { color:#000; font-size:12px; }

strong          { font-weight: bold; }
em              { font-style: italic; }

/* Headings */

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-weight: bold; color:#000 }

h1 { font-size:24px; }
h2 { font-size:22px; padding-bottom: 15px; }
h3 { font-size:18px; }
h4 { font-size:14px; }
h5 { font-size:14px; }
h6 { font-size:14px; }

/* Misc */

.date {}
.footer-text {text-align:center}
.thumbs {padding: 10px}


#wrapper {
    display: block;
    height: 300px;
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
}
#container { display:block; background-color:#FFC; float:left;
height: 300px; width: 900px; overflow:auto; }

#slider {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 4;
}

.slides {
    width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slides ul { 
    width: 5400px;
    position: relative;
    -moz-animation: slide 36s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: slide 36s infinite;
    }

.slides li { 
    float:left; 
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    }
.slides a { text-decoration:none;}

h5 {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 10px;
    font-size:24px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    -moz-animation: headings 36s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: headings 36s infinite;
}

.slides ul:hover,
.slides ul:hover h5  {
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}


@-moz-keyframes slide {
    0%  {left: 0;}
    15% {left: 0;}

    20%, 30% {left: -900px;}
    35%, 45% {left: -1800px;}
    50%, 60% {left: -2700px;}
    65%, 75% {left: -3600px;}
    80%, 90% {left: -4500px;}

    100%{left:0px;} /* Reset to Zero */
}

@-moz-keyframes headings {
    15%, 20%, 30%, 35%, 45%, 50%, 60%, 65%, 75%, 80%, 90% 
    {bottom: 5px;}
    18%, 33%, 48%, 62%, 78%, 93% /* 2% before the 1st column */
    {bottom: -200px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0%  {left: 0;}
    15% {left: 0;}

    20%, 30% {left: -900px;}
    35%, 45% {left: -1800px;}
    50%, 60% {left: -2700px;}
    65%, 75% {left: -3600px;}
    80%, 90% {left: -4500px;}

    100%{left:0px;} /* Reset to Zero */
}

@-webkit-keyframes headings {
    15%, 20%, 30%, 35%, 45%, 50%, 60%, 65%, 75%, 80%, 90% 
    {bottom: 5px;}
    18%, 33%, 48%, 62%, 78%, 93% /* 2% before the 1st column */
    {bottom: -200px;}
}
```

Comment: I would wrap the floated elements in a div set to `overflow:hidden` to avoid this issue. It's much cleaner that way.

Comment: It would be better if you narrowed the code down you shared to isolate the issue. Not only does it make it more readable for others but you yourself may also find it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Removing the `margin-top:50px` from the `#menu` style worked for me but I don't have the social media icons loaded. Not sure if they'd have an effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preferably, wrap a div around the top items and set it to `overflow: hidden`. But if you want to leave the HTML as it, try the same on the menu:

```
#menu {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

(Works for me in testing on your code.)

Comment: Also, Mal's comment worked too. But editing the #Menu did nothing.